# How to simulate people in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking at using Gazebo for simulating people and the Gazebo feature page lists this as one of its features. I was wondering if this element actually exists and where the relevant documentation is on this capability?

Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1932/how-to-simulate-people-in-gazebo?/) by [Steve M](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/271/steve-m/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters) is the tutorial you are looking for.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1